# Switch between Flutter web and flutter mobile development in VS Code

Tags: flutter, dart, web, visual-studio-code, mobile

So I have 2 different projects in my visual studio code, for flutter web development and mobile development ...

I see the tutorial if want to make flutter web must switch "**flutter channel master**", but when I switch it to master my mobile project got an error.

So my problem is every time I want to switch projects between I must change channels to **master** for web and **stable** for mobile?

is there any way to do it without switching channels? thanks sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That tutorial is *old* (in Flutter terms).

Flutter is in active development and rapidly growing. Features that where experimental and then beta become releases in the stable branch quite fast if you are used to other languages and frameworks.

Development for the web has been in the Stable branch for about a year now.

You can just use stable for both mobile and web applications.